# Duplicating Environments

Tags: macros, environments

When I want to globally modify a command in my document, I will often use a duplicated version of the original in the stencil, with the help of the `\let` macro.  For example, if I wanted to do something every time I created a section, I might say:

```
\let\svsection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{\mychanges\svsection{#1}}
```

It just dawned on me that I don't know how or if something similar can be done for environments.  What I would hope for is something like (I'm omitting arguments for the sake of simplicity, don't focus on that):

```
\let\svfigure\figure
\renewenvironment{figure}{\blahblah\begin{svfigure}}
                         {\end{svfigure}\moreblah}
```

Of course, this syntax won't work because `\figure` isn't a command.

But, I was hoping that the creation of environment `abc` would always be accompanied by the creation of associated constructed commands, for example, `\start@abc` and `\end@abc`, such that these associated commands could be `\let` to duplicate the original environment.

I also realize that one approach may be to "patch" the original environment, but I don't think that is really what I'm asking, since I'm not sure a patch can be easily undone, whereas redoing a `\let` in the opposite direction (e.g., `\let\section\svsection`) will totally undo the effects of redefinition.

It would be a handy feature to know how to duplicate an environment, so that the original copy can be `\renew`ed in the fashion I describe.

Comment: `\begin{foo}` always issues the command `\foo` and `\end{foo}` issues `\endfoo` defining it to `\relax` if it doesn't exist (which is why `\begin{large}...\end{large}` actually works). These commands _are_ defined by `\newenvironment{foo}{}{}`

Comment: @cgnieder So you are saying `\let\svfigure\figure` and `\let\endsvfigure\endfigure` actually creates an environment `svfigure` which is a copy of `figure`? If so, post the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Is your question inspired by this one? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116651/frame-and-background-color-for-all-figures 'Cos I was wondering the same thing myself when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes, the cited question got me thinking about it (again).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes in many cases this works. It wouldn't work for the `verbatim` environment or for `amsmath`'s `align` environment, for example.

Comment: you just renew the inner commands, ie, for myenvironment, you would renew \myenvironment or \endmyenvironment.

Comment: @cgnieder  It sounds like you have the makings of a very informative answer, with caveats and everything.

Comment: Related question: [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you define an environment with

```
\newenvironment{foo}[1]{start code with #1}{end code}
```

what happens internally (after some checking for optional arguments, testing if the environment exists, and taking care of a possible star argument to `\newenvironment`) essentially boils down to

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{start code with #1}% actually \new@command
\def\endfoo{end code}
```

This means if the environment has no optional arguments

```
\let\myfoo\foo
\let\endmyfoo\endfoo
```

copies the environment `{foo}` as environment `{myfoo}`. (If it has an optional argument `\LetLtxMacro` should be used instead of `\let`, see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro).)

In the `article` class the `{figure}` environment is defined as

```
\newenvironment{figure}
               {\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
```

so saying

```
\let\myfigure\figure
\let\endmyfigure\endfigure
```

works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{foo}[1]{start foo with (#1)}{end foo}

\let\myfoo\foo
\let\endmyfoo\endfoo

\let\myfigure\figure
\let\endmyfigure\endfigure

\begin{document}

\begin{myfoo}{arg}
  bar
\end{myfoo}

\begin{myfigure}
  copied figure
  \caption{my figure}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some environments like `{verbatim}` or AMSmath's `{align}` cannot be copied this way since they need to find `\end{verbatim}` or `\end{align}`, respectively, exactly.

Comment: I'd mention `\LetLtxMacro` for the cases when the environment has optional arguments.

Comment: @egreg I have! :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see it; but I upvoted anyway. ;-) However `\LetLtxMacro` is not only "safer", but it's "the right tool to use".

Comment: Do you want to edit `\LetLtxMacro` to `\NewCommandCopy`? the linked question changed as well.

Answer (score 17):

Patching `\section` as you do is not an especially good way to proceed, because you lose all the flexibility of the original command; one always has to look how a command is defined, before patching it. You'll discover that `\section` has *no* argument, for instance.

The same holds for environments; they are realized through a pair of commands: with

```
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
  {something with #1 at the start}
  {something at the end}
```

LaTeX defines `\foo` and `\endfoo` in a way basically equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{something with #1 at the start}
\def\endfoo{something at the end}
```

In standard LaTeX the `\end...` command is always parameterless (and `\newcommand` wouldn't allow to define it).

It's also important to know *when* the commands are executed; here's the definition of `\begin`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3944:
\def\begin#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}
```

Apart from some details, what happens with `\begin{foo}` is that LaTeX essentially does

```
\begingroup<bookkeping stuff>\foo
```

with some bookkeeping for later checks in the `\end` part. Similarly, `\end{foo}` will do

```
\endfoo<checks>\endgroup
```

Thus the same method used for ordinary macros will work; however,

```
\let\svfigure\figure
\let\endsvfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}
  {\blahblah\begin{svfigure}}
  {\end{svfigure}\moreblah}
```

wouldn't be a particularly good way to patch the `figure` environment. For one thing, a typing mistake `\end{fiugre}` in the input file would result in the puzzling message

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{svfigure} on input line 11 ended by \end{fiugre}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.13 \end{fiugre}
```

and users will not understand it because they have no idea about the `svfigure` environment they have *never* started. The usual solution is to say

```
\let\svfigure\figure
\let\endsvfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}
  {\blahblah\svfigure}
  {\endsvfigure\moreblah}
```

so that the `<bookkeeping stuff>` will be done for `figure` but not for the inner `svfigure`.

However, not all environments are happily redefined this way.

Environments taking an optional argument should use `\LetLtxMacro` (with `\usepackage{letltxmacro}`) instead of `\let`, but this is true also for macros.  For the `\end...` command `\let` is always sufficient. More importantly, this way of doing might not work with environments defined with different tools, notably `\NewEnviron` (`environ` package) or `\NewDocumentEnvironment` (`xparse` package).

Some other environments have their own peculiarities: don't try redefining `lrbox` (which wouldn't make sense anyway), nor `verbatim`. Something like

```
\let\svverbatim\verbatim
\let\endsvverbatim\endverbatim
\renewenvironment{verbatim}
  {<something>\svverbatim}
  {\endsvverbatim<something>}
```

will simply not work and keep you in permanent verbatim mode unless you load the `verbatim` package. But don't try this for changing the font size in `verbatim`, it won't work.

Patching macros and environments is sometimes an arcane activity best suited for necromancers rather than even skilled LaTeX programmers.

Comment: "But don't try this for changing the font size in verbatim, it won't work."  Indeed, I know a different trick for accomplishing that.  Thanks for the great answer, as always.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using LaTeX 2023-06-01 or later<sup>1</sup>, the commands `\NewEnvironmentCopy`, `\RenewEnvironmentCopy`, and `\DeclareEnvironmentCopy` are built into the kernel, so you can use:

```
\NewEnvironmentCopy{<new env>}{<existing env>}
```

to make a copy.  This will work regardless if the environment was defined using `\newenvironment` or `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.  This method should be preferred over using `\let`, because it won't fail in case the environment takes optional arguments or things like that.

The same release adds `\ShowEnvironment{<env>}` to see the definition of an environment on the terminal.

<sup>1</sup> Meanwhile you can use the [`-dev` format](https://www.latex-project.org//news/2023/03/13/latex-dev-1/).

Comment: Some brief documentation can be found in [`ltnews37`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/ecf19e5aa0eaea9ad4b98fa066cbbbd148289c01/base/doc/ltnews37.tex#L252) (when it is released), and [source code in `source2e` → ltdefns](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/4a5526b50dd0dcd6e4a9995313f38e0c37cf93bf/base/ltdefns.dtx#L1710).

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for verb conjugation tables. This is a supplemental answer to Clemenses ;) answer.

- create an environment for the present tense
- create a duplicate command (macro)
- duplication this environment for all other tenses

Why? Later I might want to adjust specific tenses (add coloring or whatever formatting changes), but for the moment I just want to get typing and have a working document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newenvironment{present}
{\leavevmode%
\begin{tabular}{ll}}{\\ \end{tabular}}%

\newcommand\duppresent[1]{\expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\present\expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\endpresent}

\duppresent{future}% copy environment present to "future"
\duppresent{perfect}% copy environment present to "perfect"

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{present}
i gea & mir gia(n)\\
du geast & eß geats/ihr geat\\
er/sie/es geat & sie gia(n) 
\end{present}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\NewCommandCopy` works. However, it has the disadvantage of requiring annoying syntax when e.g. environment name containing `*` is needed.

You can implement your own `\NewEnvironmentCopy` as follows (in newer LaTeX kernels `\NewEnvironmentCopy` is built-in so it may be a better idea to use `\ProvideDocumentCommand` that will silently fallback to use the existing command if it's already defined):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{m}{hello #1}{end #1}

\begin{test}{aaa}
    environment body
\end{test}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideDocumentCommand \NewEnvironmentCopy {mm} {
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname end#2\endcsname
}

\ProvideDocumentCommand \RenewEnvironmentCopy {mm} {
    \expandafter \RenewCommandCopy \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
    \expandafter \RenewCommandCopy \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname end#2\endcsname
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnvironmentCopy{testb}{test}
\RenewEnvironmentCopy{testb}{test}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldalign*}{align*}

\begin{testb}{aaa}
    environment body
\end{testb}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{test}{m}{redefined #1}{stop #1}

\begin{testb}{aaa}
    environment body
\end{testb}

\begin{oldalign*}
    1 &= 1
\end{oldalign*}

\end{document}
```

Note that if you use `\let` instead of `\NewCommandCopy` then the behavior would be different and unexpected (try it yourself).

---

Alternatively (which may or may not be applicable depends on the specific use case), you can use the hook system in LaTeX:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\AddToHook{env/align*/begin}{x}
\AddToHook{env/align*/end}{y}

\begin{align*}
    1 &= 1 \\
    2 &= 2
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```