# Copy the abstract environment for acknowledgments

Tags: environments, abstract

I would like to create an `acknowledgments` environment that's simply the duplicate of the `abstract` environment, with two exceptions:

1. It should print `Acknowledgments` as its heading, not `Abstract`.
2. The `acknowledgments` environment should end with `\clearpage`.

The answer to [Duplicating Environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments) shows me how to duplicate an environment, but what do I need to do to accomplish the two points above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\let\acknowledgments\abstract
\let\endacknowledgments\endabstract
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1]
\end{acknowledgments}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems easier to define the `acknowledgments` environment as an "`abstract` wrapper" using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}
  {\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments}% Abstract > Acknowledgements
   \begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}
   \clearpage}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1]
\end{acknowledgments}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The name redefinition to `Acknowledgments` is temporary within the environment group.

Comment: why appears warning message: `Overwriting file './mystyle.sty'.`? and how it could be solved?

Comment: @juanuni: When you load the [`filecontents` package](//ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) it allows one to overwrite `mystyle.sty` with every compilation if you use `\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.sty} ... \end{filecontents*}`. Without the `filecontents` package, the file won't be overwritten if it's already in the working folder.