# (Re-)newenvironment that contains environment itself with an argument in LaTeX

Tags: environments, multicol

How can I redefine an environment with an argument such as the multicols environment? The Goal is to define two sets of commands each of them based on the native multicols environment:

```
\LetLtxMacro\oldmulticols\multicols
% first command
\newenvironment{mastermulticols}[1]
    { do some stuff \begin{\oldmulticols}{#1}
    {\end{\oldmulticols} do some stuff}

% second command
\renewenvironment{multicols}[1]
    {do some other stuff \begin{\oldmulticols}{#1}
    {\end{oldmulticols} do some other stuff}
```

It is important to me that I can use the second command with `\begin{multicols}{some number}`because there are already many occurrances of `\begin{multicols}`in my document. So make two different environment with `\newenvironment{}` with two different names is not helpfull to me.

I saw the approach with the `\LetLtxMacro\oldmulticols\multicols`command in an answer by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116748/124181) dealing with the figure environment that takes no additional argument.

My problem is that I don't know the exact syntax to do so. Can anbody help me with this issue?

Comment: Defining `\oldmulticols` does not provide the old `\endmulticols` automatically

Comment: Somewhat special case of [macros - Duplicating Environments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need `\LetLtxMacro` in this case. Rather you should not redefine the environment with an argument: just pass it to the saved macro (unless you need to do something at the very start of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\FMmulticols\multicols
\let\endFMmulticols\endmulticols

\renewenvironment{multicols}
 {<some stuff before>\FMmulticols}
 {\endFMmulticols<some stuff after>}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{A section title to show it works}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different (and even more flexible) strategy is with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{multicols}{%
  <some stuff before>%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{multicols}{%
  <some stuff after>%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{A section title to show it works}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

For implementation reasons, it is not really possible to define an environment in terms of `multicols`, because this one checks explicitly for `\end{multicols}`.

Here's a generic approach that can be combined with the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` approach for adding stuff to the standard `multicols`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% keep copies of the original to be on the safe side
\let\FMmulticols\multicols
\let\endFMmulticols\endmulticols

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newmulticolsenvironment}[3]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}{#2\FMmulticols}{}%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\endFMmulticols#3}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname end#1\endcsname{\the\toks@}%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname end#1\endcsname
    {\@checkend{multicols}}
    {\@checkend{#1}}
    {}{}%
}

\newmulticolsenvironment{mastermulticols}
 {<some stuff before>}
 {<some stuff after>}

\begin{document}

\begin{mastermulticols}{2}[\section{A section title to show it works}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mastermulticols}

\end{document}
```

### Addition for the *-version

With some stretch, we can also define the *-version for every environment we define with `\newmulticolsenvironment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% keep copies of the original to be on the safe side
\let\FMmulticols\multicols
\let\endFMmulticols\endmulticols
\letcs\FMmulticolsstar{multicols*}
\letcs\endFMmulticolsstar{endmulticols*}
\patchcmd{\FMmulticolsstar}{\begin{multicols}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endFMmulticolsstar}{\end{multicols}}{}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newmulticolsenvironment}[3]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}{#2\FMmulticols}{}%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\endFMmulticols#3}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname end#1\endcsname{\the\toks@}%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname end#1\endcsname
    {\@checkend{multicols}}
    {\@checkend{#1}}
    {}{}%
  \newenvironment{#1*}
    {#2\FMmulticolsstar\begin{#1}}
    {\endFMmulticolsstar\end{#1}#3}%
}

\newmulticolsenvironment{mastermulticols}
 {<some stuff before>}
 {<some stuff after>}

\begin{document}

\begin{mastermulticols*}{2}[\section{A section title to show it works}]
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{mastermulticols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't seem to work when defining a new environment (like OP's `mastermulticols`), i.e., when using `\newenvironment{mastermulticols}` instead of `\renewenvironment{multicols}`. (Haven't yet looked at the second approach.)

Comment: @gernot For implementation reasons, also `mastermulticols` should be defined with `\FMmulticols` and `\endFMmulticols`, not with `\begin{FMmulticols}` and `\end{FMmulticols}`.

Comment: Yes, sure. But in your code, replacing `\renewenvironment{multicols}` by `\newenvironment{mastermulticols}` and `\begin/\end{multicols}` by `\begin/\end{mastermulticols}` leads to the error `\begin{mastermulticols} on input line 15 ended by \end{multicols}`.  So your solution does not yet address the second request.

Comment: @gernot Yes, I hate when the LaTeX developers use for their packages tricks that go against their own guidelines. `;-)`

Comment: Shouldn't `\@checkend{mastermulticols}` be `\@checkend{#1}`?

Comment: @clemens Yes, of course!

Comment: @egreg thank you for this great answer it worked perfectely although I do not fully understand what is going on inside the `\newcommand`definition.

Comment: @egreg is there a way to manipulate the `\newcommand`definition so that the mastermulticols can be used with with an *? maybe `\FMmulticols*` ? to use it afterwards as `\begin{mastermulticols*}`

Comment: @paescu Your wish is my command