# Create Same Latex Environment with a Different Name

Tags: environments

I am using exam class. I have an environment called solution which when I run Latex it appears as Solution with a capital letter S. Sometimes I'd like to show two different answers for the same question, so I want to call them Solution 1 and Solution 2. These two answers should have the same environment like Solution. How can I do this?
BTW, I run the following code when I want to create a solution:

```
\begin{solution}
bla bla
\end{solution}
```

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, addpoints, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] bla ...
 
\begin{solution}
bla...
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a complete minimal working example of what you've got so far?

Comment: I added a sample code above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments

Answer (score 2):

`exam` uses the macro `\solutiontitle` to format its solution. We can locally redefine it to get numbers added to it:

**Edit:** as suggested by [@AlanMunn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581154/create-same-latex-environment-with-a-different-name/581158?noredirect=1#comment1461953_581158) I also added a variant which is automatically numbered and for which you can use LaTeX's label mechanism.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, addpoints, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\newenvironment{namedsolution}[1]
  {%
    \def\solutiontitle{\noindent\textbf{Solution #1:}\enspace}
    \begin{solution}%
  }
  {\end{solution}}

\newcounter{solution}
\newenvironment{csolution}%
  {%
    \refstepcounter{solution}%
    \def\solutiontitle{\noindent\textbf{Solution \thesolution:}\enspace}%
    \begin{solution}%
  }
  {\end{solution}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question[2] bla ...
  \begin{namedsolution}{Bla}
    bla...
  \end{namedsolution}
  \begin{namedsolution}{Baz}
    BAZ\ldots
  \end{namedsolution}

  \question[3] Foo \ldots
  \begin{csolution}\label{sol:bar}
    Bar\ldots
  \end{csolution}
  \begin{csolution}
    Similar to solution \ref{sol:bar}, also baz\ldots
  \end{csolution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Great answer.

Comment: Possibly more general would be to create a counter (reset every `\question`) and eliminate the need for an argument to the macro. This would have the added advantage of allowing `\ref` to the solutions in any discussion of them.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes, that's true and would be better if the solutions should always be numbered, I'll add some code.