# how to change the background color of a figure in latex

Tags: floats, color, backgrounds

I insert a figure in my latex. But I want to make the background of the figure to be blue. How could I achieve that?

```
\begin{figure} [t]%[htbp]%[f]

\centering
\includegraphics[width= 0.65\linewidth]{./figs/BFSall.pdf} 
\caption{\color{blue}(a) BFSa-kNN; (b) BFSb-kNN.}
\label{implementationBFSKNN}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages? (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Could you please also add some clarification: Do you want to change the background color of the actual image that you include (and that is not available to us) or do you want to add a colored back around the image and the caption?

Comment: Regarding your use of `\olor{blue}` inside of `\caption`: If you want to color all captions in your document that way, you might want to use the `\caption` package in combination with `\captionsetup{textfont={color=blue}}`.

Comment: Probably related if your question is about a colored box around the whole `figure` environment:  [Frame and background color for all figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116651/134144)  or [Rounded corner colored box around figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31545/134144). Related if it is more about changing the actual background color of the image (if it currently is transparent): [ADDING white background to an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76509/134144)

Comment: it is impossible to say, you could use `\fcolorbox` to put a blue panel behind the figure, but if the figure is not transparent it will have no effect. If the background within the figure is (say) white rather than transparent you will need to edit the source of the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdframed` package can add a coloured background if the bg of the pdf is transparent

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!50,linecolor=blue!50]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4-landscape.pdf}
\caption{text}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!50,linecolor=blue!50]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4-landscape.pdf}
\end{mdframed}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted.